# Graph API list joined Teams where isArchived =false

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am following information from [C# teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) and while this works fine I would like to only download data whereby the property 'isArchived' = false. Is it possible to add a filter to do this?

I could loop through the collection after I have downloaded the data and eliminate based on this value but it seems like an extra step to perform and there are a lot of teams to loop through.

```
var joinedTeams = await graphClient.Me.JoinedTeams
.Request()
.GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Filter(...)` method on the request object:

```
var joinedTeams = await graphClient.Me.JoinedTeams
    .Request()
    .Filter("isArchived eq false")
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: When I try this I get a 400 Bad Request response with the message `Filter on property 'isArchived' is not supported.`

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using mostly HTTP requests , not sure about the exact syntax, especially in the filter value, but it should be very similar to this one. You may need to play the `"isArchive eq False"` section a bit.

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("$filters", "isArchive eq False")
};

var joinedTeams = await graphClient.Me.JoinedTeams
    .Request( queryOptions )
    .Filter("isArchive eq False")
    .GetAsync();
```